# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' (using sklearn - ExtraTreesRegressor)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Just trying out the Sklearn python library and I re-purposed some code I was using for Linear regression to fit a regression tree model as an example I saw (here's the example code):

```
def fit(self, X, y):
        """
        Fit a Random Forest model to data `X` and targets `y`.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like
            Input values.
        y: array-like
            Target values.
        """
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.n = self.X.shape[0]
        self.model = ExtraTreesRegressor(**self.params)
        self.model.fit(X, y)
```

Here's the code I've written/repurposed

```
data = pd.read_csv("rmsearch.csv", sep=",")
data = data[["price", "type", "number_bedrooms"]]
predict = "price"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

etr = ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor
etr.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = etr.score(x_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy; ", acc)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
etr.fit(x_train, y_train)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I know fit() takes 'X', 'y', and 'sample_weight'  as input. but, sample_weight defaults to none.  the other examples haven't helped me much but it could also be that I'm fairly new to python and not able to spot a simple coding error.

fit() documentation:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.fit

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
etr = ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor
etr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

You need to instantiate `ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor` before calling `fit` on it. Change this code to

```
etr = ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor()
etr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

You get the seemingly strange error that `y` is missing because `.fit` is an instance method, so the first argument to this function is actually `self`. When you call `.fit` on an instance, `self` is passed automatically. If you call `.fit` on the class (as opposed to the instance), you would have to supply `self`. So your code is equivalent to `ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.fit(self=x_train, x=y_train)`.

For an example of the difference, please see the example below. The two forms are functionally equivalent, but you can see that the first form is clunky.

```
from sklearn import ensemble

# Synthetic data.
x = [[0]]
y = [1]

myinstance = ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor()
ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.fit(myinstance, x, y)

etr = ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor()
etr.fit(x, y)
```