# Multiple Linear Regression - TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as lm

x = data_all[combi_list[0][1:]]
y = data_all[combi_list[0][0]]

lm.fit(x, y)
```

I am trying to create a multiple linear regression model with 2 independent variables on 'x' and 1 dependent variable 'y'.

Can't seem to understand why this error `TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'` keeps coming up.

**Data Types**

1. type(data_all) = pandas DataFrame
2. type(combi_list) = list containing lists

I've tried to follow a similar code which works.
https://datatofish.com/multiple-linear-regression-python/

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm

Stock_Market = {'Year': [2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016],
                'Month': [12, 11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                'Interest_Rate': [2.75,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.25,2.25,2.25,2,2,2,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75,1.75],
                'Unemployment_Rate': [5.3,5.3,5.3,5.3,5.4,5.6,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.9,6,5.9,5.8,6.1,6.2,6.1,6.1,6.1,5.9,6.2,6.2,6.1],
                'Stock_Index_Price': [1464,1394,1357,1293,1256,1254,1234,1195,1159,1167,1130,1075,1047,965,943,958,971,949,884,866,876,822,704,719]        
                }

df = pd.DataFrame(Stock_Market,columns=['Year','Month','Interest_Rate','Unemployment_Rate','Stock_Index_Price'])

X = df[['Interest_Rate','Unemployment_Rate']] # here we have 2 variables for multiple regression. If you just want to use one variable for simple linear regression, then use X = df['Interest_Rate'] for example.Alternatively, you may add additional variables within the brackets
Y = df['Stock_Index_Price']
 
# Correct up to here

# with sklearn
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, Y)

print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this code cause that error? In the code, you have both `X` and `y`: `regr.fit(X, Y)`, which should be fine

Comment: Yep, the code that I wrote throws up the TypeError. Both codes are similar, is there something that i am missing out that cause the code to fail?

Comment: Tried to run it, works fine for me @tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as lm

x = data_all[combi_list[0][1:]]
y = data_all[combi_list[0][0]]

lm.fit(x, y)
```

you have not instantiated the [`sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), but you are using the instance method `.fit()`. You need to instantiate the object before calling `.fit()`.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = data_all[combi_list[0][1:]]
y = data_all[combi_list[0][0]]

lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x, y)
```

From [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223374/typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y-using-sklearn-ex/63223389#63223389):

> You get the seemingly strange error that `y` is missing because `.fit` is an instance method, so the first argument to this function is actually `self`. When you call `.fit` on an instance, `self` is passed automatically. If you call `.fit` on the class (as opposed to the instance), you would have to supply `self`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction @jakub

Comment: My pleasure, @Tom. If this answered your question, please click the green check mark to mark it as the answer.